# If an assistant referee commits a mistake in a football game, will he be penalized in any way?

Tags: football, english-premier-league

Manchester United got two allowed offside goals in their recent EPL game against West Ham United. They were horrible mistakes by the assistant referees which they can not afford to make, considering the importance of each point in EPL(which is highly competitive).

So will they be penalized in any way so that they do not repeat such mistakes in the subsequent matches?

Comment: What you're referring to is not a *penalty* as such - it's no different to a player being dropped to the bench for poor performance. Referees from a lower panel will be given a chance to prove that they are more deserving of the position. Penalties are only imposed against match officials for unethical/unprofessional conduct, e.g. [drunkenness during a match](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVkFVgqhYlk), [match fixing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avm1MSkYLGU) (which may also involve criminal charges) and [assaulting players](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jv9S_qw8zFU).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The referees for the Premier League, Football League and FA competitions are appointed by the [Professional Game Match Officials Limited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_Game_Match_Officials_Board). When referees make frequent and/or glaring errors in matches, the PGMOL reprimands them in the form of demotion to a lower tier of the Football League.

In the 2009-10 season, [referee Mike Jones was demoted to the Championship](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2009/oct/19/beach-ball-referee-demoted-sunderland-liverpool) after incorrectly awarding a goal to Sunderland against Liverpool, after Darren Bent's shot at goal deflected off a beach ball into the goal. Later in the same season, [referee Mike Dean and assistant referee Simon Beck were demoted to the Championship](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2010/apr/07/mike-dean-demotion-alex-ferguson) following poor performances in a match between Manchester United and Chelsea. Dean failed to award a penalty each to both sides for tackles in the box and also allowed a goal to stand when he should have called a handball, while Beck failed to give an offside decision for Didier Drogba that led to a Chelsea goal.

In the game between West Ham United and Manchester United referenced in the question, only the second goal scored by Zlatan Ibrahimovic was offside. The other decision in the match that drew criticism was the harsh red card shown to West Ham's Sofiane Feghouli. It is up to the PGMOL to consider if these two decisions are significantly erroneous to warrant a reprimand against Mike Dean or assistant referee Simon Long.